Prevent children reload when data change using React.lazy components
Im trying to split my React components, and allow me to load some parts in a dinamic way, so i create 2 components in this way:
    const PluginComponent = ({ pluginComponent }) => {

    const DynamicComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`../components/${pluginComponent}.jsx`));
        const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
        input: '',
        output: ''
    });
        const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [name]: value
        }))
        console.log(formData)
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>This is the {pluginComponent} plugin component.</p>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <DynamicComponent
                    formData={formData}
                    handleInputChange={handleInputChange}

                />
            </React.Suspense>
        </div>
    );
};
export default PluginComponent;

const ExamplePlugin = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <input name="input" defaultValue={formData.input} onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" className="grow" placeholder="name here..." />
        </>
    );
};
export default ExamplePlugin;

My problem is, if i leave the formData and handleInputChange logic in the ExamplePlugin, all is working correctly, and the data is updates with no issues, but when i move the logic to the PluginComponent, and pass to the children as props, every time i change the input value, the children realoads completly, appearring the "loading" message, and cause the input to lose the focus for the reload.
is there a way to use the parent to store the data and logic, allow the children to use that for the inputs, and prevent the children to reload completly on every change?

If it's to prevent children from reloading on every change useMemo is something worth trying:
const DynamicComponent = useMemo(() => {
    return React.lazy(() => import(`../components/${pluginComponent}.jsx`));
}, [pluginComponent]);


yeah, appear this fix the issue, thk!
